# Python ElementTree child

Tags: python, elementtree

Would there be a way to end each Setting node instead of carrying over at the end?  The extra /setting/setting/setting end tags is what im looking to get rid of.   I use set but something tells me I should be using append or something to add additional setting names instead of creating subelement of setting.

```
The code is generating:(I want to remove the /Setting/Setting/Setting?)
Payload returned = <
update_app_profile odpApiToken="6b" odpCmd="save" odpExt="6629" odpUser="profileApiUser">
<dynamicsettings>
    <Group Name="BASE">
        <Setting Name="CTInt" Value="44">
        <Setting Name="CTTime" Value="11:11:11">
        <Setting Name="CTList" Value="Half-Life 2">
        <Setting Name="Regexp_Base" Value="STR1">
        <Setting Name="CTDate" Value="2016-01-01">
        <Setting Name="CTString" Value="qwe" />
        </Setting></Setting></Setting></Setting></Setting>
     </Group>
  </dynamicsettings>
</update_app_profile>



def create_post_request(self, odpExt, odpCmd, dict):
    '''
    <?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8">
    <update_app_profile odpCmd="save" odpUser="sgoel" odpPwd="sgoel123" odpExt="8114">
      <dynamicsettings>
        <Group Name="ApplicationParameters">
            <Setting Name="CTTemp1" Value="12"/>
            <Setting Name="CTTemp2" Value="test1"/>
        </Group>
      </dynamicsettings>
    </update_app_profile>
    '''
    dict = {'.//CTDate':'2016-01-01', './/CTString': 'qwe', './/Regexp_Base': 'STR1', './/CTTime': '11:11:11', './/CTInt': '44', './/CTList': 'Half-Life 2'}
    root = ET.Element("update_app_profile")
    root.set("odpCmd", odpCmd)
    root.set("odpExt", odpExt)
    root.set("odpUser", "profileApiUser")
    root.set("odpApiToken", "6b")

    tree= ET.SubElement(root,"dynamicsettings")
    #tree.set("Group Name", "Group1")
    tree = ET.SubElement(tree, "Group")
    tree.set("Name","BASE" )
    #tree = ET.SubElement(tree, "Setting")

    #tree.append("Setting")


    for item, value in dict.iteritems():
        print item + value
        tree = ET.SubElement(tree, "Setting")
        tree.set("Name", item[3:])
        tree.set("Value", value)

    #tree.set("ApplicationParameters")

    return ET.tostring(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
tree = ET.SubElement(tree, "Setting")
tree.set("Name", item[3:])
tree.set("Value", value)
```

With:

```
setting = ET.SubElement(tree, "Setting")
setting.set("Name", item[3:])
setting.set("Value", value)
```

Then the settings will all be subelements of one `tree`.